# PHP Garbage Collection Kicks in Late

Tags: php, session, garbage-collection

I want to know exactly when the garbage collect is going to run so I made the test script below.

```
<?php

ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime',10);
ini_set('session.gc_probability',1);
ini_set('session.gc_divisor',1);

echo ini_get('session.gc_maxlifetime').'s ';
echo ini_get('session.gc_probability').'/';
echo ini_get('session.gc_divisor')."<br>";

session_start();
echo session_id();
if (isset($_SESSION['test']))
{
    echo "<br>";
    echo "session set";
}
$_SESSION['test'] = "works";
echo "<br>";
print_r($_SESSION);

?>
```

Try #1: When I first try it I get:

```
10s 1/1
e9isrrljuvdbr1c6vqndp1e4i7
Array ( [test] => works )
```

Try #2: I wait more than 10 seconds and get:

```
10s 1/1
e9isrrljuvdbr1c6vqndp1e4i7
session set
Array ( [test] => works )
```

Try #3: Then any time after that I get:

```
10s 1/1
e9isrrljuvdbr1c6vqndp1e4i7
Array ( [test] => works )
```

Why does garbage collection not kick in on try #2 but kick in on try #3?

Comment: Seems like `session_start()` reads the session and only after that runs GC

Comment: From the documentation `Garbage collection may occur during session start...` Why would it erase the session after reading it? That would be insane, though it appears that's what it's actually doing.

Comment: the most precise answer can give some guy who is confident enough in php sources. We can only guess :-)

Answer (score 1):

The PHP garbage collection for session data is designed to eventually clean the data, not to guarantee it is cleaned.

If you start a session, PHP tries to find already stored session data from last request. Failing this, it will assume the session is brand new, create an empty session file on disk, lock it, and initialize $_SESSION as empty array.

At the end of the script, or when `session_write_close()` is called, the contents of $_SESSION is serialized to this file, the lock is released, and the script ends.

Only then the garbage collection kicks in, with a probability (i.e. only one out of 100 requests starts the garbage collection). It scans all session files for expiration, and if a files last modification time is older that the `session.gc_maxlifetime` setting, it gets deleted.

In fact, `session.gc_maxlifetime` is mislabeled. It really is `session.gc_minlifetime`, because the session data lives AT LEAST this amount of time.

Second thing: The garbage collection cannot throw away the session you are actively using, because it's data is freshly saved.

Third: Garbage collection needs a request to trigger it. It is not an automated process in the background.

Combining points two and three results in garbage collection cleaning away only the OTHER sessions that are old enough to be older than `session.gc_maxlifetime`. To test it, you would need at least TWO sessions, one to expire, and the second to trigger executing the garbage collection.

So it should go like this: Have two browsers, access the session page with both. Reload the page in one browser regularly, wait more than `session.gc_maxlifetime` seconds in the second browser. Only then reload in the second browser - session should be gone.

Comment: session.gc_minlifetime does make more sense. But the documentation says `Garbage collection may occur during session start (depending on session.gc_probability and session.gc_divisor).` But above you claim garbage collection happens at the end of the script. Also you claim that a session can't trigger it's own garbage collection, but try #3 shows that this is not true.